# Passar array como parametro não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Preciso passar um array como parametor para uma função, cada valor do array tem o nome de uma imagem e a função deveria carregar cada uma dessas imagens como `img/foto1`, `img/foto2`, etc. Mas ele não está passando os valores do array, está passando simplesmente a palavra "Array", o que me retorna `img/Array`. Tentei utilizar o método `implode`, mas quando o uso, ele não separa em array e passa o valor `img/foto1foto2foto3` em uma só tag img. Poderiam me ajudar ?

Minha função em JavaScript que deveria retornar as imagens:

```
function galerias(parametroGal){
    var query = new Array(parametroGal);

        var imgs = document.querySelector("#gallery");
        var x = 1;

            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
            imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

        for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++){
            imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+query[i]+"'class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
        imgs.innerHTML += "<a class='row' href='pics.html?gal="+x+"'><div class='twelve columns link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";
        x++;

}
```

Minha função que faz a consulta no banco de dados:

```
function consultarDados($query){
    $dbResult = array();
    $conexao = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
    mysql_select_db($this->banco, $conexao);
    $rs = mysql_query($query, $conexao);
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
            array_push($dbResult, $rows);
        }
    return $dbResult;
    mysql_close($conexao);
}
```

Na minha página de galerias, eu faço a query desta forma:

```
<?php 
    include 'connectDB.php';
    $conexao = new connectDb();
    $galeria_1= $conexao->consultarDados('select * from portfolio where gal= 1 and theme= 1');

    $parametroGal = array();
    foreach($galeria_1 as $result){

            array_push($parametroGal, $result['nome']);
        }

?>
```

E é assim que eu passo o array `$parametroGal` como parametro para a função em JavaScript:

```
<?php
        echo'galerias("'.$parametroGal.'");';

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) para isso:

```
<script>
    galerias(<?php  echo json_encode($parametroGal); ?>);
</script>
```

Do jeito que você estava fazendo, tratava o `Array` do PHP como se fosse uma string. Para funcionar, você precisa transformar o `Array` do PHP em um `Array` do Javascript.

Altere também o Javascipt para:

```
function galerias(query) {
    var imgs = document.querySelector("#gallery");
    var x = 1;

    imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

    for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++){
        imgs.innerHTML += '<img src="img/'+query[i]+'" class="imgs-galeria"" />';
    }

    imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "<a class='row' href='pics.html?gal="+x+"'><div class='twelve columns link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>";
    x++;

}
```

Não é preciso instanciar um novo Array no Javascript pois o parâmetro já chegará como um array.

Veja um [exemplo funcionando no PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/h3mp-ig6p).

Comment: Ainda me retornou img/foto1_1.jpg,foto1_2.jpg,foto1_3.jpg,foto1_4.jpg :/

Comment: E o valor do parametro ficou como galerias(["foto1_1.jpg","foto1_2.jpg","foto1_3.jpg","foto1_4.jpg"]);

Comment: Ainda me trouxe o mesmo retorno, todas as imagens em uma unica tag. Tentei utilizar o split para dividir em arrays na função JS mas não consegui...

Comment: Acho que é algum problema no Javascript agora, estou simulando aqui para tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Tambem acho, e obrigado, tambem estou tentando por aqui..

Comment: Consegui fazer com que apareçam as imagens. Veja o javascript alterado na reposta. Também removi aquela alteração no array_push, deixe como estava no início: `array_push($parametroGal, $result['nome']);`

Comment: Perfeito ! Muitissimo obrigado !